# Angular Promise not resolved

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise

I have a `subscribe` function in my class which subscribes to a state of a checkbox toggle:

```
public subscribe(): void{
   ...
// Subscribe to toggle subject state
    this.subscription = this.isSet$
      .pipe(
        // Skip initial toggle state
        skip(1),
        // Update persisted FCM enabled state
        tap(isSet => {
          localStorage.setItem(PushService.localStorageKey, String(isSet));
        }),
        // Switch between function calls based on the toggle state
        switchMap(isSet => (isSet ?
          this.requestToken()
            .then(() => {
              console.log('RESOLVED REQUEST');
              this.cbDisabled = false;
            }) :
          this.deleteToken()
            .then(() => {
              console.log('RESOLVED DELETE');
              this.cbDisabled = false;
            }))))
      .subscribe();
}
```

The 2 Promises in the `switchMap` look like that:

*REQUEST*

```
private requestToken(): Promise<any> {

    console.log('REQUEST TOKEN FROM FIREBASE');

    return this.afMessaging.requestToken.pipe(
      mergeMap(deviceToken =>
        this.http.post<void>(
          formatEndpointUrl(environment.endpoints.communicationservice.web_push.register_device),
          {deviceToken}
        )
      )
    ).toPromise();
  }
```

*DELETE*

```
private deleteToken(): Promise<void> {

    console.log('DELETE TOKEN CALLED');

    return this.afMessaging.getToken.pipe(
      tap((deviceToken) => {
        this.afMessaging.deleteToken(deviceToken);
        console.log('DELETING TOKEN IN FIREBASE');
      }),
      mergeMap(deviceToken =>
        this.http.delete<void>(
          formatEndpointUrl(environment.endpoints.communicationservice.web_push.delete_device, {deviceToken})
        ).toPromise().then(() => {
           console.log('DELETING TOKEN IN BACKEND');
        })
      )).toPromise();
  }
```

When I toggle the Switch to OFF, it deletes the Token, the log looks like this:

```
DELETE TOKEN CALLED
DELETING TOKEN IN FIREBASE
DELETING TOKEN IN BACKEND
RESOLVED DELETE
```

However, when I toggle the Switch to ON, I get this:

```
REQUEST TOKEN FROM FIREBASE
```

and that is it, the Promise never gets resolved. What am I missing?

Comment: Inside `switchMap` you should use  `return this.requestToken()...`  your token requests

Comment: I get a syntax error when I do this, could you post a snippet? only putting `return` before the two methods don't work. Sorry if thats a stupid question

Comment: Why are you creating promise it should be Observable and angular http already is Observable all you need to remove `.toPromise()` and return `return this.http.post...` in your token methods

Comment: This becomes very confusing very quickly because you are mixing promises and observable operators. For example, a switchMap should return an Observable. Either go full promise or fully observable (preferred)..